# Delete All file and sub-folder Except the main folder

Tags: android

I am new android app

In some part of my app , I need to delete all file and sub-folder in /data/data/PACkAGE_NAME/ but keep the main folder

i have root accesses also ! and shell commend

i Have used  two methods but at both of them the package folder has deleted

method 1 :

```
public static void ClearData(String Dir) {

    String sCommand = "rm -rf " + Dir + "*";
    Command command = new Command(0,sCommand);

    try {

        RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RootDeniedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

method 2 :

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {

    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            boolean  success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // The directory is now empty so delete it


    return dir.delete();
}
```

tnx

EDIT : I found solution :

public static void ClearData(String Dir) {

```
    String sCommand = "rm -rf " + Dir + "/*";
    Command command = new Command(0,sCommand);

    try {

        RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RootDeniedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one is a classic example of recursion.  That would be worth learning about, especially if you are deleting files and folders.

The easiest way to not delete the top level is to keep track of your depth in the recursion tree, something like:

```
public static boolean deleteDir(File dir, int depth) {
```

And each time you call deleteDir you now add the second argument of 'depth+1' and you can then avoid doing the 'dir.delete()' when your depth is 0.

Once you've got that, then when you call deleteDir from your program, you need to supply the second argument of '0', or else call the arguments by name.

Having said all that, it might be easier to just delete the whole directory and then recreate it, but you won't want to do that if something is relying on the existence of the directory.